# Unable to make aws sts get-caller-identity from private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sts, assume-role

I have followed this blog post link https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-instance-access-bucket carefully and it works partially which means if I call from EC2 instance running behind a private subnet (with no Internet Gateway, No route to NAT Gateway, etc) then it does not work at all and I get timed out (**Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"**):-

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --profile Allow_Instance_Profile_EC2_to_Access_S3
```

However, if I run the same `aws sts` command on another EC2 instance running behind a public subnet then it works like a charm. (Please note that I have attached the same instance profile role to both EC2 instances).

After researching a lot, I found that when we do `aws sts` then it takes a public route to the **STS Token service** hence it requires a public IP. To overcome this limitation, I then created a VPC Interface Endpoint for STS service as sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com and attached it to my custom VPC that has only the private subnets thinking that it would resolve the issue if I ran the same command again from the private EC2 instance but again it timed out.

I'm using a custom VPC with only private subnets to run my application. I tried running an EC2 in the public subnet of the default VPC (just to see if my instance profile role is fine or not). I wanted to establish this whole connectivity on my instance running behind a private subnet (of custom VPC). I would really appreciate it if you could advise on its root cause.

Following is the configuration of STS Interface Endpoint:-
[image]

I'm very close to solving this issue and I have done everything from head to toe and really getting frustrated.

Kindly suggest how to solve this issue.

[Additional Details]
Few troubleshooting I did based on suggestions but seems like some firewall is blocking the traffic. Reason is if I try this command `ping sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and behind the scene when I go to VPC and deleted the Interface Endpoint (for STS) then all of a sudden I started getting this destination unreachable ICMP messages:-

```
From ip-10-0-153-8.ec2.internal (10.0.153.8) icmp_seq=1507 Destination Host Unreachable
From ip-10-0-153-8.ec2.internal (10.0.153.8) icmp_seq=1508 Destination Host Unreachable
From ip-10-0-153-8.ec2.internal (10.0.153.8) icmp_seq=1509 Destination Host Unreachable
From ip-10-0-153-8.ec2.internal (10.0.153.8) icmp_seq=1510 Destination Host Unreachable
From ip-10-0-153-8.ec2.internal (10.0.153.8) icmp_seq=1511 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com ping statistics ---
1512 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1311 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1571423ms
pipe 4
```

I then created a new **Interface Endpoint for STS** and tried again to ping it but still gets timed out eventually. I can definitely confirm that DNS Hostnames and DNS resolutions are enabled on this custom VPC (that contains only 2 private subnets).
[image]
[image]

Also, **in the security group** of **Interface Endpoint of STS**, I have allowed all incoming traffic (for time being), refer their screenshots.
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

So it is all whitelisted from the Security Group as well. May I know what next I should debug? I feel like I'm close to solving it, tired but do not want to give up on this issue.

Any help would really be appreciated.

[Added Network Reachability Analyzer] -> Reachable as per the screenshots but ping to `ping sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` still timed out if manually done from the EC2 instance (refer to screenshot)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[New VPC Logs while doing the Reachability Analyzer):-

**eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 (of EC2 Instance Connect Endpoint)**

```
2023-09-12T08:42:21.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488341 1694488372 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:42:27.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488347 1694488378 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:42:30.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 10.0.149.231 10.0.153.8 39871 22 6 6 448 1694488350 1694488352 ACCEPT OK
2023-09-12T08:42:30.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 10.0.153.8 10.0.149.231 22 39871 6 4 280 1694488350 1694488352 ACCEPT OK
2023-09-12T08:42:55.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488375 1694488406 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:42:56.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488376 1694488407 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:42:59.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488379 1694488410 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:43:27.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488407 1694488439 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:43:31.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 10.0.149.231 10.0.153.8 39871 22 6 6 448 1694488411 1694488412 ACCEPT OK
2023-09-12T08:43:31.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 10.0.153.8 10.0.149.231 22 39871 6 4 280 1694488411 1694488412 ACCEPT OK
2023-09-12T08:43:55.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488435 1694488466 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:43:56.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488436 1694488467 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:43:59.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488439 1694488470 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:44:20.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488460 1694488492 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:44:28.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 - - - - - - - 1694488468 1694488499 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:44:30.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 10.0.149.231 10.0.153.8 39871 22 6 6 448 1694488470 1694488472 ACCEPT OK
2023-09-12T08:44:30.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 10.0.153.8 10.0.149.231 22 39871 6 4 280 1694488470 1694488472 ACCEPT OK
```

**eni-07523ca7c37243b2b (of Private EC2 Instance)**

```
2023-09-12T08:40:46.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-07523ca7c37243b2b 10.0.149.231 10.0.153.8 39871 22 6 55 4816 1694488246 1694488396 ACCEPT OK
2023-09-12T08:40:46.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-07523ca7c37243b2b 10.0.153.8 10.0.149.231 22 39871 6 45 6241 1694488246 1694488396 ACCEPT OK
2023-09-12T08:43:46.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-07523ca7c37243b2b 10.0.153.8 10.0.149.231 22 39871 6 8 560 1694488426 1694488516 ACCEPT OK
2023-09-12T08:43:46.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-07523ca7c37243b2b 10.0.149.231 10.0.153.8 39871 22 6 12 896 1694488426 1694488516 ACCEPT OK
```

**eni-0e2793b7226a717d6(of STS Interface Endpoint)**

```
2023-09-12T08:40:43.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0e2793b7226a717d6 - - - - - - - 1694488243 1694488315 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:41:04.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0e2793b7226a717d6 - - - - - - - 1694488264 1694488343 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:41:17.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0e2793b7226a717d6 - - - - - - - 1694488277 1694488356 - NODATA
```

**eni-0dc4385564f4a3814 (of STS Interface Endpoint)**

```
2023-09-12T08:40:25.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0dc4385564f4a3814 - - - - - - - 1694488225 1694488320 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:40:27.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0dc4385564f4a3814 - - - - - - - 1694488227 1694488306 - NODATA
2023-09-12T08:41:04.000+05:30   2 458419607076 eni-0dc4385564f4a3814 - - - - - - - 1694488264 1694488350 - NODATA
```

As per the logs, I can say that the request is not reaching two ENI's of the STS Interface Endpoints from my private EC2 instance but the reachability analyzer is saying as reachable which is a **false alarm**.

Comment: what is your default AWS region? Make sure to use the matching regional endpoint to send your AWS STS requests.

Comment: it is us-east-1 only

Comment: What does the security group of the vpc endpoint look like? What about its policy?

Comment: I have a custom VPC with 2 Private subnets only (no Internet gateway, no NAT Gateway attached in this VPC). I have attached VPC Gateway (for S3) and Interface Gateway (for STS) in this custom VPC. I'm unable to make call to STS using private EC2 instance excepting the call to traverse via Interface Endpoint(for STS) to STS to get the token. In the security group of Interface Endpoint of STS, I have allowed all incoming traffic.  I can definitely confirm that DNS Hostnames and DNS resolutions are enabled on this custom VPC (that contains only 2 private subnets).

Comment: Can you resolve the DNS name of the endpoint?

Comment: I have added new VPC logs that show that the request not reaching the STS Interface Endpoints when doing the reachability analyzer but the status on reachability analyzer shows reachable both are contradicting.

Comment: Any luck? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: My issue was security groups. Perhaps check that?

Comment: When analyzing paths to VPC Endpoints with VPC Reachability Analyzer, you may want to restrict the destination address of the analysis to match the Public IP address of the service you are trying to hit. If you don't, the analysis might be technically correct, but for a different IP address than the one you really meant to check _(You can expand the `Packet Header` in the solution/blocked path RA gives you to see what is being used)_.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable Private DNS names in the Interface Endpoint, otherwise you need to specify the custom DNS name created for that endpoint like this `aws sts get-caller-identity --endpoint-url https://vpce-xxxxxxxxx.sts.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com`.

When Private DNS names is enabled it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: It is not working. Private DNS is already enabled. I'm using a custom VPC with only private subnets to run my application. I tried running an EC2 in the public subnet of the default VPC (just to see if my instance profile role is fine or not). I wanted to establish this whole connectivity on my instance running behind a private subnet (of custom VPC). I would really appreciate it if you could advise on its root cause.

Comment: You can use VPC Flow logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: I have enabled the VPC flow logs....and attached in the question....not able to figured out anything

Comment: Is this the ENI of the VPC Endpoint `eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05`?

Comment: Well, assuming the `eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05` ENI is the VPC Endpoint's, the NODATA means that the ENI didn't receive any traffic in that period of time. You can use the Reachability Analyzer service to see if there is connectivity between your instance and the VPC Endpoint. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html

Comment: eni-0b65a12cfc0782b05 belongs to EC2 Instance Connect Endpoint and not for sts endpoint.

Comment: I have added the network reachability analyzer status and it is reachable only....but still ping to sts manually on EC2 instance does not work and timed out

Comment: Did you try all of what is described here? https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/vpc-fix-gateway-or-interface-endpoint

Comment: This may sound silly, but have you tried to create another EC2 instance on the same subnet and run the `aws sts` command?

Comment: I have added new VPC logs that show that the request not reaching the STS Interface Endpoints when doing the reachability analyzer but the status on reachability analyzer shows reachable both are contradicting.

Comment: `ping` doesn't work. You need to use `telnet` to test connectivity. Just run `telnet sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 443`

Comment: with telnet, I got this response, [ec2-user@ip-10-0-153-8 ~]$ telnet sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 443
Trying 10.0.145.192...
Connected to sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Well, you do have connectivity to the VPC Endpoint. Did you try with another EC2 instance?